# What is a tank capacitor?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

This is from a microchip datasheet

[image]

What is a tank capacitor ? It doesn't sound like a tank circuit because why would they use "capacitor" and not the other element in the tank.

Comment: It is an English only idiom, like the "LC tank"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just another way of saying "bulk capacitor". You can tell from the size and conditions (far from supply).

Comment: Oh. Well that was lame. I was expecting some new type capacitor or capacitor topology. lol. Appreciated!